# How to stop nginx on my Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, recompile

I am trying to recompile nginx in order to add the page speed module.  Never done anything like this before so a little scared!  I am the step after doing "make" where I want to stop nginx.  The problem is it seems like it restarts itself because my site never goes down and if I keep running the command it keeps stopping it with a new ID each time:

```
[ec2-user@ nginx-1.6.0]$ sudo service nginx stop
Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66:  9107 Killed                  env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}

[ec2-user@ nginx-1.6.0]$ sudo service nginx stop
Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66:  9131 Killed                  env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}

[ec2-user@ nginx-1.6.0]$ sudo service nginx stop
Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66:  9151 Killed                  env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}

[ec2-user@ nginx-1.6.0]$ sudo service nginx stop
Stopping nginx: /sbin/service: line 66:  9171 Killed                  env -i PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}
```

So now I am scared to do a make install while my Nginx is still running because I know I am supposed to stop it before doing a make install.  What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like there is an upstart script that keeps Nginx up and running.  After running this command I was able to stop Nginx:

```
sudo initctl stop nginx
```

Comment: after running this command I got the this error                                                     
         """   initctl: Unknown job: nginx  """

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx.service
```

This command will stop Nginx from your EC2 instance, further we also have the following commands to start and also to know the status of Nginx

```
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
```